# tictactoe errors when i try to launch it on virtual device

Tags: java, android

i have this code for a tictactoe android app

class XSI0

```
package xsi0.cristi.ro;

import java.util.Random;

public class XSI0 {
private char Tabla[];
private final static int MarimeTabla=9;

public  final char User='X';
public  final char Android='0';
public  final char SpatiuGol= ' ';

private Random mRand;

public  int getMarimeTabla(){
    return MarimeTabla;
}

public XSI0(){
    Tabla=new char[MarimeTabla];
    for(int i = 0; i < MarimeTabla; i++)
        Tabla[i]=SpatiuGol;
    mRand=new Random();
}

public void curataTabla(){
    for(int i=0;i<MarimeTabla;i++)
    {
        Tabla[i]=SpatiuGol;
    }
}

public void setMiscare(char jucator,int locatie){
    Tabla[locatie]=jucator;
}

public int getMiscareComputer(){
    int miscare;

    for(int i=0; i<getMarimeTabla();i++){
        if(Tabla[i]!=User && Tabla[i]!=Android){
            char curr=Tabla[i];
            Tabla[i]=Android;
            if(verificaCastigator()==3){
                setMiscare(Android,i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                Tabla[i]=curr;

        }
}

    for(int i=0; i<getMarimeTabla();i++){
        if(Tabla[i]!=User && Tabla[i]!=Android){
            char curr=Tabla[i];
            Tabla[i]=User;
            if(verificaCastigator()==2){
                setMiscare(Android,i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                Tabla[i]=curr;

        }
}

do{
    miscare=mRand.nextInt(getMarimeTabla());
}while(Tabla[miscare]==User || Tabla[miscare]==Android);

setMiscare(Android,miscare);
return miscare;
    }
public int verificaCastigator(){
    for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){//victorie orizontala
        if(Tabla[i]==User &&
           Tabla[i+1]==User &&  
           Tabla[i+2]==User)
            return 2;//castiga jucator
    }

        for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
            if(Tabla[i]==Android &&
               Tabla[i+1]==Android &&   
               Tabla[i+2]==Android)
                return 3;//castiga android
    }

        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){//victorie verticala
            if(Tabla[i]==User &&
               Tabla[i+3]==User &&  
               Tabla[i+6]==User)
                return 2;//castiga jucator
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            if(Tabla[i]==Android &&
               Tabla[i+3]==Android &&   
               Tabla[i+6]==Android)
                return 3;//castiga android
        }

        if(Tabla[0]==User &&//victorie diagonala
            Tabla[4]==User &&
            Tabla[8]==User ||
            Tabla[2]==User &&
            Tabla[4]==User &&
            Tabla[6]==User)

            return 2;//castiga jucator

        if(Tabla[0]==User &&//victorie diagonala
                Tabla[4]==Android &&
                Tabla[8]==Android ||
                Tabla[2]==Android &&
                Tabla[4]==Android &&
                Tabla[6]==Android)

                return 3;//castiga android

        for(int i=0;i<getMarimeTabla();i++)
        {
            if(Tabla[i]!=User && Tabla[i]!=Android)
                return 0;//jocul nu s-a terminat
        }

        return 1;//remiza
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
package xsi0.cristi.ro;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
//import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.view.*;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private XSI0 mGame;

private Button[] mBoardsButtons;

private TextView mInfoTextView;
private TextView mHumanCount;
private TextView mTieCount;
private TextView mAndroidCount;

private int mHumanCounter=0;
private int mTieCounter=0;
private int mAndroidCounter=0;

private boolean mHumanFirst=true;
private boolean mGameOver=false;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBoardsButtons = new Button[mGame.getMarimeTabla()];
    mBoardsButtons[0]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.unu);
    mBoardsButtons[1]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.doi);
    mBoardsButtons[2]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.trei);
    mBoardsButtons[3]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.patru);
    mBoardsButtons[4]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cinci);
    mBoardsButtons[5]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sase);
    mBoardsButtons[6]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sapte);
    mBoardsButtons[7]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.opt);
    mBoardsButtons[8]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.noua);

    mInfoTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Info);
    mHumanCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.uwins);
    mTieCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Drawscount);
    mAndroidCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.defeatscount);


    mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
    mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
    mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

    mGame=new XSI0();

    incepeJocNou();
}

private void incepeJocNou(){
    mGame.curataTabla();

    for(int i=0;i<mBoardsButtons.length;i++){
        mBoardsButtons[i].setText("");
        mBoardsButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
        mBoardsButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));


    }

    if(mHumanFirst){
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.Utilizatorul_primul);
        mHumanFirst=false;
    }

    else{
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_android);
        int move=mGame.getMiscareComputer();
        setMove(mGame.Android,move);
        mHumanFirst=true;
    }

}

private void setMove(char player,int location){
    mGame.setMiscare(player, location);
    mBoardsButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
    mBoardsButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
    if(player==mGame.User){
        mBoardsButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
        else
            mBoardsButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);





}

private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    int location;
    public ButtonClickListener(int location){
        this.location=location;
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!mGameOver){
            if(mBoardsButtons[location].isEnabled()){
                setMove(mGame.User,location);

                int winner=mGame.verificaCastigator();

                if(winner==0)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_android);
                    int move=mGame.getMiscareComputer();
                    setMove(mGame.Android,move);
                    winner=mGame.verificaCastigator();
                }

                if(winner==0)
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_utilizator);
                else if(winner==1){
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.rezultat_egal);
                    mTieCounter++;
                    //mTieCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));

                    mGameOver=true;
                }
                else if(winner==2){
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.utilizator_castiga);
                    mHumanCounter++;
                    //mHumanCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                    mGameOver=true;
                }

                else{
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.android_castiga);
                    mAndroidCounter++;
                    //mAndroidCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                    mGameOver=true;
            }
        }

    }
}




/*public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}*/

    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Information"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/PlayArea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unu"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/unu"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doi"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/doi"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trei"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/trei"
            android:textSize="80sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/patru"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/patru"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cinci"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/cinci"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sase"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/sase"
            android:textSize="80sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sapte"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/sapte"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/opt"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/opt"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/noua"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/noua"
            android:textSize="80sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PlayArea"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/info"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRaw4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/w"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Victorii" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uwins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Draws"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Egaluri" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Drawscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/defeats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Infrangeri" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/defeatscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And I am getting this errors:

```
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{xsi0.cristi.ro/xsi0.cristi.ro.MainActivity}:         java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at xsi0.cristi.ro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 01-03 00:47:36.503: E/AndroidRuntime(831):     ... 11 more
```

When I Try to launch the app it appears "the aplication has stopped unexpectedly".
I've followed the tictactoe tutorial from youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't initialized `mGame` before calling `getMarimeTabla()` on it. Move the line `mGame=new XSI0();` to before where you call `getMarimeTabla()` on it like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGame=new XSI0();  // initialize the variable first
    mBoardsButtons = new Button[mGame.getMarimeTabla()];
```